# exit with value returned by command stored in variable

Tags: bash

I have a command that is constructed within a variable in a bash script, like so:

```
CMD="cowsay "
CMD+="-n "
CMD+="foo-moo"
```

I want to run this command, then exit the script with the return value of the command. I can do:

```
${CMD}
exit $?
```

But is there some way of doing this as a single action (i.e. without using `$?` or similar)? I tried variations on the following but could not achieve the desired result myself.

```
exit "$(${CMD})"
```

Comment: Boy! Linefeeds must be really expensive in your part of the world ;-)

Comment: Your approach is trying to exit using the text output from your command.

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes - this is why I mentioned that it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Heh, really I don't like to use this way in case the two statements get split up, for example by an `echo "Command finished"` or something

Comment: `result=$?` followed by `echo "Command finished"` then `exit $result` maybe?

Comment: But I can also see someone wanting to debug your script by adding `echo result was $?`. Perhaps `${cmd};cmd_ret=$?` then `exit $cmd_ret` is a reasonable compromise?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`exec ${CMD}`

That will replace the shell with your command, which has the effect of returning the command's result.